# WRT54G router restarts every time I connect to it with my phone

Tags: android, wrt54g

My WRT54G router usually works fine with my roommate's laptop and my laptop. However, whenever I connect my Sony Xperia Pro, the router drops all connections and restarts itself. Then I have to power cycle the router to be able to connect the laptops again.

Would anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "drops all connections"? Do you mean wireless clients no longer detect a wireless network?

Comment: @david-schwartz, I think so. It disconnects both laptops and the phone before restarting itself.

Sorry, don't think I used the term right ;^_^

Comment: Do you have the latest firmware? If not, update. If so, try switching to Tomato or ddWRT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search yielded an interesting hit.  Although not exactly your issue, it does involve your router and some Sony hardware trying to connect wireless.  It involves using a static setup on a PS3, while including the uPnP options that like to automatically do that setup.  Check it out [here](http://homecommunity.cisco.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/WRT54G-reboots-when-connecting-to-PS3/td-p/117200).

There's also a thread on Sony's site that seems to be your issue, fairly exactly, though a different router.  A firmware update on the router seemed to fix their issue.  Check it out [here](http://talk.sonymobile.com/thread/5771).

One way or another, you're just having a conflict somewhere with settings between the two devices.

If you don't have a bunch of custom configuration on the router, I'd recommend first updating the firmware, and then restore to factory defaults.  See if you have the issue with a clean slate.

Comment: Sorry to have taken so long (understatement of the year) getting back to this question. Firmware update on the phone fixed it. Thanks :)